# How to Write statement to delete in batches of 1000

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql

Below is the code that needs to be re-written in order to delete in batches of 1000 since this code here causes our table to balloon.

Goal:
Re-write the delete statement inside the job to delete in batches of 1000

```
@command=N'exec system.dbo.sp_global_SQLExec_RunOnAllCompanies ''delete from alohaftplog where date < convert(varchar(15),getdate() -30,101)''',
```

Comment: What is the definition of `sp_global_SQLExec_RunOnAllCompanies` ?

Comment: stored proc to run through the companies in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add TOP 1000 in the delete the statement:

```
delete TOP 1000 from alohaftplog where date < convert(varchar(15),getdate() -30,101)
```